# Eloquent sync that does not delete old entries and set specific value to one of their pivots fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have ManyToMany relation between Customer and Product. The association table `customer_products` has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_products` (
  `customer_id` int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `customer_products`
--
ALTER TABLE `customer_products`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`,`product_id`),
  ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`);
```

In other words, the schema is `customer_id`,`product_id` and `status`.

When I update the product's customers, I do not want to delete the absent customer ids, so I placed the `status` field to be 1 for existing active customer, and 0 for the removed customer.

I need to keep things simple in the update action, so I need `sync()` method that does not delete the absent customer_ids and also update their respective `status` to 0.

The process here should include two steps:

1. Update `status` field for absent `customer_id` to be 0
2. Create new record for any new `customer_id` added with status value 1

I have tried `sync()` with the `false` parameter, and `syncWithoutDetaching()` but it has no any action for the pivot `status` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From devk answer, I have the following solution that will depend on two foreach loops.

```
foreach($request->customers as $id){ //Loop 1
        $product
        ->customers()->sync([$id=>['status'=>1]],false);
        //$product->save();

       }
       foreach($product->customers()->get() as $cust){ //Loop2
           if (!in_array($cust->id,$request->customers)){
            $product
            ->customers()->sync([$cust->id =>['status'=>0]],false);
           }
       }
       /* Not needed
       $product //Create new record if found
        ->customers()
        ->sync($request->customers,false);
        */
```

In Loop1, any submitted customer id, will be created or updated to have status 1

In Loop2 any customer id already recorded in the relation, that not found in the customers ids array, will be updated to status 0.

I have suggested to Laravel ideas a suggest about new method called [`softSync`](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1103)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`->attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) instead. And [`updateExistingPivot`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.php#L177) for updating `status`

Edit, because `updateExistingPivot` does not actually take an array

Something like that (assuming relation name "customers"):

```
// Update some customer statuses to 0
$product
    ->customers()
    ->updateExistingPivot([ids to set the status to 0], ['status' => 0]);

// Then add new ones
$product
    ->customers()
    ->attach([new ids], ['status' => 1]);
```

**Edit**

I misunderstood the process. Best I solution I can come up with is with 3 steps:

```
$customerIds = [1, 2, 3];

// Update all customers' statuses, that are not
// in the passed array to 0
$product
    ->customers()
    ->newPivotStatement()
    ->whereNotIn('customer_id', $customerIds)
    ->update(['status' => 0]);

// Update the rest to status = 1
$product
    ->customers()
    ->newPivotStatement()
    ->whereIn('customer_id', $customerIds)
    ->update(['status' => 1]);

// Sync the array
$product
    ->customers()
    ->sync($customerIds, false);
```

Comment: The problem here is that new ids in `->attach([new ids])` is not always new ids, so for the table schema shown above, it is more probably to generate SQL error for duplicate key value

Comment: I see. Then how about replacing my `->attach()` with `->sync([ids], false)`, that should work since `status` defaults to `1`.

Comment: The first part of your snippet will set status for all relation records to 0, then `sync([ids],false)` will only create new records for submitted new  keys with status 1, since, the submitted ids may contain new and old ids, so the old ids will be set to 0 too, i.e softly deleted mistakenly.

Comment: It doesn't need to set all records to status = 0. You could chain additional query to scope it to only certain records, like this: `$product->customers()->where('some_col', 'some_val')->updateExistingPivot(...)`.

Comment: To clarify the issue, there is a list of `customers` submitted.  this list should be the guide to do one of the three cases: 1. create new customer_id, product_id and status  record if there is no any previous customer_id related to that product_id with status 1. 2. change the status from 0 to 1 if it already found, 3. any alreday recorded customer_id that does not found in customers its status will be 0

Comment: Ok yeah I understand now. I updated the answer, that's the best I can come up with. There might be better solutions though. The first 2 statements in my answer can probably be reduced to 1 query, but I don't think there's an elegant Eloquent solution for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168473/discussion-between-saidbakr-and-devk).

Comment: The solution you suggested leads to any pivot record that has no customer_id in the submitted list to get status `0` even it was related to another product. I have implemented another solution, I will regard it as an answer for more discussion about it.